# Built a n-variate distribution with given correlations and specific marginal distributions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution, copula

I want to built a $n-$variate density with the constrains that  all the marginals must be the same (i know the marginal distribution) and the correlation between the component $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ of the n-variate density must be a given $\rho_{ij}$.

How can i do it?

It seems to me that the answer is  "use the copula", but i really don't understand how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as THE copula. Using different copula families will generate different multivariate distributions having the same correlation matrix and identical margins, but still a different spread (thinking of a scatterplot in the bivariate case). The Normal and student copula have the nice property, that the correlation matrix directly relates to the parameter set. Hence, this set-up would be rather easy. Other copula families and construction might need a bit more thought to generate a sample following the desired correlation matrix. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Ben I have this marginal, and I need a multivariate distribution. I'm aware that the same marginal can have different joint distribution. I just need to understand how built some joint distributions, then among all the possibile joints, I can make a decision. Are you willing to explain how a Gaussian or a student copula works?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understood your comment correctly. The way to "build some joint distribution" is Sklar's Theorem (here 2D): H(x,y) = C(F(x),G(y)) with margins F of X and G of Y and copula C. The Gaussian and student copulas are defined based on their multivarite distributions, dropping the margins (substituting x with F^-1(u) and y with G^-1(v) in Sklar's Theorem). Please note that correlations (Pearson) on the original scale are influenced by the margins, Kendall's tau measures correlation on the copula scale and allows for some families to be translated into the copula's parameter.